# How could I optimize this following program in R to boost performance? (Monte Carlo simulation involving compute-intensive permutation test)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, optimization, statistics

Hi I'm trying to optimize the following program for a Monte Carlo Power study. I first use an algorithm taken from *Efron and Tibshirani (1993)* to find the p-value of a permutation test (upper-tailed) for equality of means. I wrote a function as follows called perm_test(), of which the output is a single p-value. Then, I call this function in another program, power_p(), that simulates 1000 permutation tests (returning 1000 p-values). My power estimate is the proportion of these 1000 p-values that are statistically significant, i.e., < 0.05. The entire process takes me about 8 minutes to run (2020 macBook pro). I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions in terms of optimizing this process to make it run quicker. Many thnx.

```
perm_test <- function(delta) {
  
  # Permutation test as described in Efron and Tibshirani (1993), (Algorithm 15.1, p208)
  
  # Draw random samples from a normal distribution
  x <- rnorm(10, mean = delta, sd = 1)
  y <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  # observed diff in means, denoted as D_obs 
  D_obs <- mean(x) - mean(y)
  
  # Create a data frame "N" with  n_x + n_y obs (20 rows in our case)
  N <- data.frame("v" = c(x, y))
  # create a group variable "g" indicating which group each observation belongs to
  N$g <- as.factor(c(rep("x", 10), rep("y", 10)))
  # arrange column "v" in ascending order 
  # notice that column "g" is also re-ordered
  N <- arrange(N, v)
  
  ###############################################################################################
  # There are 20 choose 10 (184756) possibilities for the ordering of "g"                       #       
  # corresponding to all possible ways of partitioning 20 elements into two subsets of size 10  #
  # we take only a random sample of 5000 from those 184756 possibilities                        #
  ###############################################################################################
  
  # Initialize variables
  B <- 5000
  x_mean <- 0
  y_mean <- 0
  D_perm <- rep(0, 5000)
  
  # Loop to randomly generate 5000 different orderings of "g"
  for (i in 1:B) {
    
    # Shuffle the ordering of "g"
    N$g <- sample(N$g)
    # Permuted means of x and y
    x_mean <- tapply(N$v, N$g, mean)[1]
    y_mean <- tapply(N$v, N$g, mean)[2]
    # Find permuted diff in means, denoted as D_perm
    D_perm[i] <- x_mean - y_mean 
    }
  
  # Find p-value 
  P_perm <- sum(D_perm >= D_obs)/ B
  
  # Output
  return(round(P_perm, digits = 5))
  
}
```

Here's the program that simulates 1000 permutation tests:

```
power_p <- function(numTrial, delta) {
  
  # Initilize variables
  P_p <- rep(0, numTrial) 
  pwr_p <- 0
  
  # Simulation
  P_p <- replicate(n = numTrial, expr = perm_test(delta))
  
  # Power estimates are the proportions of p-values that are significant (i.e. less than 0.05)
  pwr_p <- sum(P_p < 0.05) / numTrial
  
  # Output 
  return(round(pwr_p, digits = 5))

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perm_test2 <- function(delta) {
  x <- rnorm(10, mean = delta, sd = 1)
  y <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  D_obs <- mean(x) - mean(y)
  v <- c(x, y)
  g <- rep(1:2, each = 10)
  B <- 5000
  y_mean <- x_mean <- 0
  D_perm <- rep(0, B)
  for (i in 1:B) {
    ii <- sample(g) == 1L
    D_perm[i] <- (sum(v[ii]) - sum(v[!ii]))/10 
  }
  P_perm <- sum(D_perm >= D_obs)/ B
  return(round(P_perm, digits = 5))
}
```

In comparison to more complicated approaches I propose the above one, where I have made some simple improvements to your existing code.

1. we do not need to use `data.frame`, that only takes unnecessary time to subset vector each time
2. instead of factor group vector we can use simple integer vector
3. the ordering of data is not needed
4. we can reduce mean calculation. In your code 2 calls of `tapply(N$v, N$g, mean)` was the slowest part.
5. `mean(x)` is slower than `sum(x)/n`, it does additional checks etc., so in this situation we can use the faster approach. As the inner loop will be executed 1000x5000 times(sims x B).

---

```
bench::mark(perm_test_org(0.5), perm_test2(0.5), iterations = 5, check = F,
            relative = T)[, 1:8]
# A tibble: 2 x 8
#   expression           min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#   <bch:expr>         <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 perm_test_org(0.5)  15.5   15.3       1        1.00     1        5    16
# 2 perm_test2(0.5)      1      1        13.5      1        1.69     5     2
```

Approximately 15x faster on my system. 1000 iterations took 33.89 seconds.

### Update 2.

We can improve speed even more by:

1. replacing `sample` with `sample.int`
2. then we see that the `g` vector isn't needed at all to select random two groups
3. in loop we do not need to sum both parts of vector `v` as we can `sum(v)` before loop, so we can do one sum less inside the loop and calculate the result values at end.

---

```
perm_test3 <- function(delta) {
  x <- rnorm(10, mean = delta, sd = 1)
  y <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  D_obs <- mean(x) - mean(y)
  v <- c(x, y)
  B <- 5000
  s <- sum(v)
  D_perm2 <- rep(0, B)
  for (i in 1:B) {
    D_perm2[i] <- sum(v[sample.int(10) < 6])
  }
  D_perm <- D_perm2 - (s - D_perm2)
  P_perm <- sum(D_perm/10 >= D_obs) / B
  return(round(P_perm, digits = 5))
}
```

Runs in +/- 20 seconds for 1000 iterations.
Now the slowest part is repeated call of `sample.int`. You can look into faster functions:
https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/04/fast-sampling-support-in-dqrng/

Comment: Thank you Minem. I appreciate your input. Believe it or not, these are some valuable insights to me. It's really the little things that could make a program go faster or slower. It's amazing. I truly appreciate your taking your time.

Comment: Maybe this could be even further improved by using `Rcpp` for the for loop

Answer (score 3):

In R, loops such as your `for (i in 1:B)` are slow.  It's almost always best to avoid them.  Here's a solution that avoids the loop entirely to perform a single permutation test.

```
start <- Sys.time()
permTest <- function(x) {
  # Create a tibble containing B replications of the sampled data
  tibble() %>% 
    expand(
      Perm=1:B,
      V=N$v
    ) %>% 
    # Randomly permute each permutation and hence randomly assign group membership 
    mutate(Random=runif(nrow(N) * B)) %>% 
    arrange(Perm, Random) %>% 
    mutate(g=rep(c("x", "y"), each=10, times=B)) %>% 
    # Calculate groupo means for each permutation 
    group_by(Perm, g) %>% 
    summarise(Mean=mean(V), .groups="drop") %>% 
    # Calculate p-value for each permutation and determine (one-sided) significance level
    pivot_wider(values_from=Mean, names_from=g) %>% 
    mutate(
      Delta=x-y,
      MoreExtreme=ifelse(Delta > D_obs, 1, 0)
    ) %>% 
    summarise(PValue=mean(MoreExtreme), .groups="drop") %>% 
    mutate(
      Power=ifelse(PValue < 0.05, 1, 0),
      Permutation=x
    )
}
```

This runs in 0.013s on my machine, suggesting that a thousand calls should take less than 15 seconds, approximately 30 times faster than the original.  However,

```
# Simulate 1000 permutation tests
Result <- bind_rows(lapply(1:1000, permTest))
```

Took 3.38 minutes (~200s) suggesting that `lapply` and/or `bind_rows` are also slow. (Or that there was significant latency on my machine.)  I expected some overhead dur to `lapply` and `bind_rows`, but I'm very surprised that the overhead is as large as it is. I don't have time to investigate further.

It is also possible to introduce the replication into the function directly:

```
permTest2 <- function(NTests) {
  # Create a tibble containing B replications of the sampled data
  tibble() %>% 
    expand(
      Perm=1:B,
      V=N$v,
      Test=1:NTests
    ) %>% 
    # Randomly permute each permutation and hence randomly assign group membership 
    mutate(Random=runif(nrow(N) * B)) %>% 
    arrange(Test, Perm, Random) %>% 
    mutate(g=rep(c("x", "y"), each=10, times=B)) %>% 
    # Calculate groupo means for each permutation 
    group_by(Test, Perm, g) %>% 
    summarise(Mean=mean(V), .groups="drop") %>% 
    # Calculate p-value for each permutation and determine (one-sided) significance level
    pivot_wider(values_from=Mean, names_from=g) %>% 
    mutate(
      Delta=x-y,
      MoreExtreme=ifelse(Delta > D_obs, 1, 0)
    ) %>% 
    group_by(Test) %>%
    summarise(PValue=mean(MoreExtreme), .groups="drop") %>% 
    mutate(
      Power=ifelse(PValue < 0.05, 1, 0)
    )
}
```

[Untested code]

But - on my machine at least - `permTest2(1000)` runs into memory problems.  Therefore, the optimal soltion will likely be a combination of `lapply` and `permTest2` with N less than 1000.  In other words, use `lapply` to run chunks of the required permutations and then aggregate to get an overall result.

@denis' solution is also reasonable.

PS: your original post wasn't quite reproducible, but your edit whilst I was witing this answer may have solved that problem.

Comment: Hi Limey. Thank you for your thoroughness. I ran your solution and, from the looks of it, everything seems to work accordingly. It'll take me some time to dive deeper into your solutions as they are very thorough and in-depth. But I wanted to thank you first for taking the time to answer my question so thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following possibility, using `data.table`. The idea is to create one unique long `data.table` using `CJ` to then do the calculations in grouping operations.

```r
power_p2  = function(numtrial,delta){
  x <- rnorm(10, mean = delta, sd = 1)
  y <- rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  D_obs <- mean(x) - mean(y)
  
  
  B <- 5000
  grouplist <- c(rep("x", 10), rep("y", 10))

  
  plouf <- CJ(it = 1:B,trial = 1:numtrial)
  Ntrial <- plouf[,.(v = c(x, y),g = sample(grouplist)),by = .(it,trial)]
  
  res <- Ntrial[,mean(v),by = .(g,it,trial)] %>%
    dcast(it + trial~g,value.var = "V1")
  pwr_p <- res[,.(p = sum(x-y>=D_obs)/B),by = trial][,sum(p <0.05)/numtrial]
  
  return(pwr_p)
}
```

The main gain of time is the use of `CJ` to generate the list of iteration from your first function, and trial from your second function.

`plouf`  is thus a Bxnumtrial table. `plouf[,.(v = c(x, y),g = sample(grouplist)),by = .(it,trial)]` produce a data.table with the `v = c(x, y)` and the sampled group `g = sample(grouplist)` for each combination of `it` and `trial`.

The table `Ntrial` contains already the Bxnumtrial version of your sampling.
The `dcast` is just to have a `x` and `y` column to easily calculate the difference of mean.

It is ~18 time faster, but I did not have the time to check properly that it does the same things than your function (I think it does, but I could have made an error)

```
microbenchmark(power_p(10,0.1),power_p2(10,0.1),times= 10 )

Unit: milliseconds
              expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
  power_p(10, 0.1) 10873.7651 11524.0682 12240.7713 11748.8152 12389.2195 16029.2265    10   b
 power_p2(10, 0.1)   568.2784   600.1486   677.1702   632.8234   741.2503   992.4752    10  a
```

Comment: Hi Denis. I appreciate your resourcefulness and your exposing me to data.table, which seems like a power package. As I am not familiar with the syntax,  I have some difficulty understanding a few lines of code in your solution. Specifically, I have trouble understanding this line and what ",." does in the square bracket [ ]:  `Ntrial <- plouf[,.(v = c(x, y),g = sample(grouplist)),by = .(it,trial)]`. Again, thank you for your time as this is quite helpful.

Comment: `plouf[,.(v = c(x, y),g = sample(grouplist)),by = .(it,trial)]` does a grouping operation on `it` and `trial`, that is a kind of loop. For each combined value of these two variables, it output the list `.(v = c(x, y),g = sample(grouplist))`, that are you x and y values, and the random association to the `g` variable. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html for basic `data.table syntax`

Comment: In data.table, `.()` is a shortcut for list.

Comment: I will take some time to get familiar with the package.  Thank you so much for your help.